# How to pass arguments to python node

Tags: ros, python, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like pass arguments to a node like so:

```
rosrun my_package my_node.py myArg1 myArg2
```

Is this possible? How do I define my python function? Currently it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('my_package')
import rospy

def my_node(myArg1,myArg2)
...
```

but when I use the command line and run rosrun I get errors saying the my function takes two arguments and 0 were passed.

Using topics to pass in information seems over complicated and I don't want to use parameters because I don't need to make myArg1 and myArg2 available to any other nodes.
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Running fuerte

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64552/how-to-pass-arguments-to-python-node/) by [anuppari](https://answers.ros.org/users/5082/anuppari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-06-07

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you aren't going to use ROS parameters, this basically a generic Python question. You should use the 'sys' module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('my_package')
import rospy
import sys

def my_node(myArg1,myArg2)
    ...

if __name__=="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print("usage: my_node.py arg1 arg2")
    else:
        my_node(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

It's also good practice (but not required) to use the <if **name**=="_*main*"> stuff so that if you import this file into another one it does not run. Finally, the above example uses **future**'s print_function so that you are Python 3 compatible.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-06-08**:
For more advanced arguments, check out the [argparse module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html)

**Comment by [anuppari](https://answers.ros.org/users/5082/anuppari/) on 2013-06-10**:
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While fergs answer is correct, you can run into some bugs error checking the length of `sys.argv`  because ROS will pass in additional arguments beyond what you give, as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Accessing_your_command-line_arguments). One annoying bug I've had is I was passing a namespace into a node, but ROS was passing in the name of a log file of the form _log_foo, and that leading underscore is disallowed as a namespace. It's a hard bug to track down. You should do

```
myargv = rospy.myargv(argv=sys.argv)
```

and then proceed as normal with `myargv`, as that function will strip out the arguments appended by ROS.

---

Originally posted by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) with karma: 642 on 2018-04-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shrini96](https://answers.ros.org/users/104316/shrini96/) on 2023-06-13**:
I agree. It is hard to track the fact that ROS is passing a ton of other things. I had simple length checking conditions, and took me a while to realise this is the reason why my nodes were not working. Thanks a lot for this alternative way of using passed arguments. Works like a charm.